# How to select ID from Locator if it's changing dyanamically after running application, How we can implement logic for it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, mendix

Here I'm trying to implement Puppeteer with mendix for UI automation, But While selecting ID as locator it is changing dyanamically, how I can change logic for it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rJJJ.png)

Comment: If possible add code apart of the question in text, not a screenshot or image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use selector for some of the static part. For example like

```
await page.waitForSelector('[id*="LoginModule.Login"]');
```

For more detail maybe can read this link
https://www.angularfix.com/2022/04/puppeteer-select-element-id-where.html